# Get project dependency DLL's in package folder from package.json

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, solution

I want to retrieve the NuGet dependency DLL's that are registered in the project package.config from the package folder.

package.config (sample):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
     <package id="Humanizer.Core" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

Structure:

```
- Folder
   - ProjectFolder
      - packages.config <-- config file
   - Packages
       - Humanizer.Core.2.6.2
            - lib
                - netstandard1.0
                    - Humanizer.DLL
                - netstandard2.0
                    - Humanizer.DLL
   - Solution
```

Now I can retrieve information from the `package.config` to get the id + version together to know in which folder I need to be in the `Packages` folder. Then I am sure there is a `lib` folder so that is fine to. But then I get stuck. Cause the `lib` folder contains a `netstandard1.0` and/or `netstandard2.0` (or others) folder while the package.config had only a `targetFramework="247"` attribute left that does not match.

Any idea how I should handle this? Maybe am doing it all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Get project dependency DLL's in package folder from package.json

**Actually**, I am confused why you get a `targetframework="247"`. I wonder if it is changed by yourself.

**So** please run `update-package -reinstall` under **Tools**-->**NuGet Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console** to reinstall your nuget and dependencies.

`targetframework` in `packages.config` file means the framework version of your current project. It refers to the framework version of your current project. Install these nuget packages into the project under this framework version.

**=======================================**

**Please note that:**

When the nuget package install its dependencies, it is pursuing the rule **Nearest wins**. It will install the dependency which is nearer to the project's framework version.

You can check [this document about how NuGet resolves package dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#nearest-wins).

**For an example**, if your project is target to `netframework4.7.2` and has dependencies like `netframework 4.7.1` and `netframework 4.6.2`, it will install the version of the dependency `net framework4.7.1` that is closest to the main project `net472`.

**As your description**, `Humanizer.Core` has dependency like `net standard 1.0` and `netstandard 2.0`,

[image]

**Also** as [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) said,

The minimum version supported by `net standard 1.0` is `net framework 4.5` and the minimum version supported by `net standard 2.0` is `net standard 4.6.1`.

===========================================================

If `net framework 4.5` <= your main project framework version < `net framework 4.6.1`.

The nuget package will install the dependency of `net standard 1.0`.

If `net framework 4.6.1` <= your main project framework version,  the nuget package will install the dependency of `net standard 2.0`.

If you have a newer version dependency and it is compatible with your main project, it will install the latest version.

**Besides**, you can upload your project and check on the `hintpath` of the `xxx.csproj` file to see which version of the dependency the project used.

[image]

[image]

If your project targets to >=`net framework 4.6.1`, it will install the `net standard 2.0` dependency.

[image]

[image]

========================

**Test**

And you can just create two projects which target to `Net Framework4.5.2` and `Net Framework 4.7.2` respectively. And then install this package in these two projects to see the behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will look into this at a later point in the upcoming days and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. And I suggest you could test it in time. haha. anyway, it depends on you:) Also, if you have any concern, please feel free to let us know in time. And if it helps you handle the issue, please do not forget to accept it :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I had the time to fix the problem. I used the xxx.csproj file to retrieve the dependencies paths and use the paths. So again, thank you :)

Comment: Little note: the `targetframework="247"` part, I did not edit by hand, and reinstall did no changes to the files etc.